# using a batch file to create a new file using two variables

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm have this working right now:

```
echo %date% %time% logon >>C:\logs\%username%.log
```

This creates a log file for each user and adds to each time they logon..

I want to create a folder using the date then create the user log..

Tried this:

```
echo %date% %time% logon >>C:\logs\%date%\%username%.log
```

But it doesn't work.. any help?

Comment: You need to create the directory first.

Comment: What format has your `%date%`? It could work with `25.06.2013` but not with `06/25/2013` as this isn't valid as a file/directory name

Answer (score 2):

this will do

```
md C:\logs\%date% 
echo %date% %time% logon >>C:\logs\%date%\%username%.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
set TS=%DATE:~10,4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%TIME:~0,2%-%TIME:~3,2%-%TIME:~6,2%

md "C:\logs\%TS%"
echo %date%%time% logon >> C:\logs\%TS%\%username%.log
```

Answer (score 1):

```
md "C:\logs\%date:/=-%"
echo %date% %time% logon >> "C:\logs\%date:/=-%\%username%.log"
```

You may select your locale date separator instead of `/`, and the character you want in the date stamp instead of `-`